# What are the main "Revisionist powers" and "satisfied power" in the world now?

Tags: terminology

I once saw the two nouns "revisionist power" and "satisfied power" in an article in a Chinese newspaper that helps the Chinese learn about the new political nouns in English. "Revisionist" was a socialist noun but the article says now it has got some new meanings. It means a power that tries to change the situation eagerly, and "satisfied power" will try its best to keep the situation. It also said that some American newspapers already called Trump a "revisionist".

Is there a better definition for the two nouns? And what are the main "Revisionist power" and "satisfied power" in the world?

Comment: Could you please link to the newspaper as well as a translation of it if possible? If not, can you please add some quotes to give it context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Revisionist" in its most basic meaning just means "believing in change".  But a country may want to change one thing and not another.  To quote the [FT](https://www.ft.com/content/e9cc014a-755c-11e9-be7d-6d846537acab)

> America and China are therefore both revisionist powers. And they are also both status quo powers. America is the status quo power on geopolitics, so it has become the revisionist power on economics. China is the revisionist power on geopolitics, so it has become the status quo power on trade.

The USA is the dominant power in the Pacific region, China wants to change that.  China has benefited from 40 years of globalisation. American wants to change the trade balance.

"Revisionist" also has other meanings, in Marxism, it means one who differs from Marx in some significant way.  In history it is often used pejoratively to mean an unorthodox and biased retelling of history that ignores known facts.

So there isn't a list of "revisionist" countries. Most countries want change in some aspects of their international relations. Most countries want some aspects of their international relations to stay the same. And the word has connotations, so may be being used as a slur.

So when people call Trump a "revisionist", this might be because he wants to change the nature of the trade relationship with China, or because he believes (in a historically revisionist way) that slavery wasn't so bad.

However, in the work of Professor Walter Russell Mead, there are three powers that are particularly revisionist in the sense of seeking a fundamental change to the post Soviet World Order:  [Russia, China, and Iran](https://www.ft.com/content/fb9a5ba6-fd4d-11e3-96a9-00144feab7de):

> The crisis in Ukraine [...] China’s increasingly assertive territorial claims and Iran’s obvious dissatisfaction with the regional order in the Middle East form the [...] pillars of the argument.